# How to sort according to value in SAS?

Tags: sas

Let's say I have a data set with the following contents, how could I then sort so that I only print the values Midfielders and Strikers along with their respective names and numbers?

```
    INPUT Position $ Name $ Number;
    DATALINES;
    Striker, Bob, 11
    Midfield, John, 8
    Midfield, Mary, 7
    Goalie, Tim, 16
    Striker, Bharat, 32
    ;
    RUN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the data (if required), with a proc sort and then print/display with proc print. 
Limit the dataset in the print statement using a where statement.

```
proc sort data=have; 
by position;
run;

proc print data=have noobs;
where position in ('Midfield', 'Striker');
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter directly to proc sort like below:

```
proc sort data=ds 
(where=(upcase(Position) contains("STRIKER") or 
        upcase(Position) contains("MIDFIELD")));
by Position;
run;
```

This is very good for big datasets and can be used with data step and lots of procs.